# Apply multiple styles to a single placeholder in an input element

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I've got a basic input element on a form:

```html
<input type="text" name="where" placeholder="Location or Place">
```

But I want to style the placeholder inline with the design below:

[image]

Currently I've got the following styles:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder, ::-moz-placeholder, :-ms-input-placeholder, input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: white;
}
```

Obviously this doesn't handle the light blue 'or' text. I'd love to do this with CSS3 where possible. It it possible to style this using just CSS?

Comment: Its showing white color i checked please see demo http://jsbin.com/vufucubi/1

Comment: Interesting but I can't think of any way to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Comment: You can set one color but you have to do ::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: white;}, ::-moz-placeholder {color: white},...
I don't think you can add another color to placeholder (span or whatever).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only solution i see is to avoid the use of placeholder and replace its behaviour with javascript. The old-style way!

[image]

**[See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vbnj2/58/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="location">
    <span class="holder">Location <span class="blue">or</span> Place</span>
  <input id="input" size="18" type="text" />&nbsp;
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $("span.holder + input").keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val().length) {
            $(this).prev('span.holder').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).prev('span.holder').show();
        }
    });
    $("span.holder").click(function() {
        $(this).next().focus();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
div.location > span.holder {
position: absolute;
margin: 5px 8px;
color: #ddd;
cursor: auto;
font-family: Helvetica;
font-size: 11pt;
z-index: 1;
}

div.location > span.holder > span.blue{
    color: #819FF7;
}

div input {
    padding:5px;
    font-size:11pt;
    background-color: #0B7DAB;
    color: white;
     border-radius:15px;
     -moz-border-radius:15px;
     -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is wondering if it is possible in 2016, but it can be achieved using only css, with `:valid` selector:

HTML:

```
<div class="holder">
<input type="text" placeholder="" required="required">
<span class="placeholder">Name <span>*</span></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.holder {
  position: relative;
}

input[required="required"]:valid + .placeholder {
  display: none;
}

.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  color: green;

}

.placeholder span {
  color: red;
}
```

[demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devxlt/4tr3n2j1/)